# Adding ScrollBar, with Frame.pack()

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

I have a program that auto updates values in a Frame -> Panel. 
Every time it updates I call Frame.pack() since the updates 
cant be seen unless I call that.

I the problem I have is that when the Frame keeps resizing all the way 
to the bottom of the screen, it kind of breaks. Since it can't keep packing
the updates into the frame. I was thinking of adding a scrollbar to the panel, since i only have one for this frame.

The scroll bar comes up when the frame packs all the way to the bottom of the screen (vertical max) and then the user can use the scroll bar to keep scrolling down.

I have tried a lot of things, but all of them failed till now.

```
 JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

 scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                   // scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 800));
                   //setWindow.setP.add(scrollPane);
                   setWindow.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve] and don't set the preferred size of the `JScrollPane`.

Comment: *since the updates cant be seen unless I call that.* - when you add components to a visible GUI you should be using `panel.revalidate()` and `panel.repaint()`, not pack(). *I have tried a lot of things* - you need to create the JScrollPane with the instance of the "panel" that you are updating. Then scrollbars will appear as you add components to the panel.